# Running Variance Inflation Factor(VIF) iteratively for a large number of features taking a long time

Tags: regression, machine-learning, interpretation, variance-inflation-factor

I am trying to do logistic regression on a dataset with 1,500 features that are very multicolinear. I care about interpretability of coefficients so I am running a VIF calculation on all columns and eliminating the highest VIF at each step until I reach about 1000 features. This process even for one step takes a very long time computationally. Is there a better or more efficient way to eliminate multicollinearity on a large number of features to prepare them for interpretable regression?
Thanks

Comment: There is, but it's complicated.  See Belsley, Kuh, & Welsch, *Regression Diagnostics.*  Also, this stepwise approach you have taken might be difficult to justify theoretically or even in practice.  Have you considered more standard approaches, such as regularization?

Comment: I want to use the logistic regression coefficients as feature importance measures as well and I read a lot of papers about how multicolinearity could mess with interpretation of LASSO and Ridge regression in this way. There is no way around interpreting a regression model until multicollinearity is gone.

Comment: You are removing variables. Lasso is a standard, far more efficient method to remove variables.  How could that possibly "mess with interpretation"?  Your last statement is dubious, too: if multicollinearity had to be removed in order to interpret regression results, almost no observational science would be able to employ regression. I wonder whether we have a shared understanding of the word "interpretation."  Could you explain what you mean by it?

Comment: By interpretation, I mean I want to rank the coefficients of the logistic regression and report the top 10 most important features for my regression in my paper.  If I do not deal with multicollinearity before running LASSO, LASSO will pick one out of a set of multicolinear features and just had that coefficient as not zero and will drive the rest to 0. It just gives me pause taking LASSO coefficients to rank a bunch of multicollinear features.

Comment: It should give you even greater pause to eliminate variables sequentially on the basis of VIF!  After all, *the very best variable* could be extremely highly correlated with all the other variables--and thereby be exactly the one you want most to *keep* in the model--yet your VIF-based procedure might eliminate it right away.  It's very difficult to tell what will happen with 1500 variables. I recommend you practice on a toy problem with, say, three or four variables, so you can develop a sense of what's going on.  BKW have very good advice: it's worth learning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. will do. To your point, if I go from 1500 features to 1000 features that are independent and I get a very good performance out of the 1000 features, I would be perfectly happy with interpreting the performance of the model based on those 1000 features. I am not trying to find causation or anything like that here, I am trying to fully interpret how my high performing model comes up with its final prediction and rank the importance of features. I kind of think with highly multicollinear features, ranking feature importances would be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  If you can reduce highly correlated variables to a large number of nearly-uncorrelated ones, you will be in a rare situation: go for it, but it's too much to hope for generally.